# function of CURP in mysql

Tags: mysql

hello how can I create a function that allows to obtain the CURP to 15 digits (without the homoclave) since the CURP contains 18 digits and it is only required to show 15 digits passing as a parameter the user id I am working in mysql

this is my table where the curp is located

```
CREATE TABLE Participant (
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Name VARCHAR (50),
     Surname P VARCHAR (50),
     Surname M VARCHAR (50),
Email VARCHAR (150),
     Telephone INT  (30),
     Curp VARCHAR (150),
IdSuburb INT,
     primary key(Id),
     CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (IdSuburb) REFERENCES Suburb(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

and this is what led to the moment

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION CURP (inName varchar (100), inId int) RETURNS varchar (15)
begin
declare name varchar (20);
set name = inName <15;
return name;
end $$
delimiter;
```

Comment: Not sure if you are asking about the data masking.  if yes, you may find the following useful : https://mysqlserverteam.com/data-masking-in-mysql/

Comment: You may be looking for [`left()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)